# How do I correctly use my inherited datas from my parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a newbie with VueJS and I'm setting up a rather simple website where the user can change some elements from the website, such as the website's background image.

From the admin part of the website, the user can upload an image that will be used as one of the page's background. The value is stored in a Rails API, and, when a user gets to the visitor's part, VueJS calls the settings from Rails, then displays it where I want them. I use `Vue-Router`, so I make the call for the settings in my `App.vue` and transmit the received datas to the `<router-view>` component. I decided to do so to load all the datas only once instead of loading them for each page change.

Here is how it looks:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <transition :name="transitionName">
      <router-view :settings="settings" :me="bio"></router-view>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      settings: null
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.$http.secured.get('/settings')
      .then(response => {
        this.settings = response.data
      })
      .catch(error => this.setError(error))
  }
}
</script>
```

**front/Landing.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="landing" :style="{background: this.settings.landing_bg.url}">
  <p>{{ this.settings.landing_bg.url }}</p>
  <!-- Some other elements, not related -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['settings'],
  created () {
    console.log(this.settings)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

I have several problems with this configuration:

- The first one is that I get errors saying that VueJS can't read "landing_bg" of null
- But VueJS has no problem displaying the image's path in the `<p>` right under it
- `console.log(this.settings)` returns `null` when I reload the page, but will display the settings correctly if I go to another page then back. However, no background image is set.
- I tried to declare with `datas()` what structure `this.settings` will have, but VueJS tells me that it doesn't like how there are two `settings` declared.

I guess this is a problem with asynchronous loads, but how should I handle that? Should I use VueX?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `this` is redundant in your `:style`, change it to:

```
:style="{ background: settings.landing_bg.url }"
```

By the way, unless your `landing_bg.url` looks like this: `url('bg_url')` you might want to create a computed property:

```
computed: {
  bgURL() { return `background: url('${this.settings.landing_bg.url}')` }
}
```

You might also have to add a `v-if` in that div to render it only after `settings` have been loaded. That error pops up because `settings` is still null when the component is created.

```
<div id="landing" :style="bgURL" v-if="settings">
```

Comment: Thanks! I also realized that my css rule wasn't correct, I forgot about `url()`

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to declare with datas() what structure this.settings will have, but VueJS tells me that it doesn't like how there are two settings declared.

No, declare it on the props, like this

```js
props: {
    'settings': {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({
            landing_bg: {
               url: '' //here you can specify a default URL or leave it blank to just remove the error
            }
        })
    },
},
```